# Firestore limit using react-infinite-scroll-component only scroll with the given limit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to create an infinite scroll with my firestore document list using react-infinite-scroll-component. I set the limit to 5 for testing. The infinite scroll is working but it only shows the given limit of 5 list:

currently I created 25 different lists, and I limit firestore to show 5 at a time:

```
list 1
list 2
list 3
list 4
list 5
loading more...
```

after it loads it will load the same 5 list back and does not load a new list, and also loads in an infinite loop with the given 5 limit:

```
list 1
list 2
list 3
list 4
list 5
list 1
list 2
list 3
list 4
list 5
loading more...
```

here is my sample code below to get the query, I put it in a useEffect because it was in a context provider wrap in the the user page and the home page, both using infinite scroll:

```
 import InfiniteScroll from 'react-infinite-scroll-component';

 const [list, setList] = useState([]);
 const [last, setLast] = useState(null);


 useEffect(() => {

   firestoreList
    .orderBy('createdAt', "desc")
    .limit(5)
    .get()
    .then((querySnapshot) => {
       const lastVisible = querySnapshot.docs[querySnapshot.docs.length - 1];
       setLast(lastVisible.data());

       const postList = []
       querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
         postList.push(doc.data()); 
       })
       setList(postList);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
       console.log(err)
    })
  },[]};
```

this is the code for the fetch data:

```
 const {list, last, setList } = ListContext(); 

 const fetchMoreData = () => {
    firestoreList
      .orderBy('createdAt', "desc")
      .startAfter(last)
      .limit(5)
      .get()
      .then(() => {
         setList(list.concat(list));
      })
      .catch((err) => {
         console.log(err)
      })
 };
```

and for the react-infinite-scroll-component:

```
   <InfiniteScroll
     dataLength={list.length}
     next={fetchMoreData}
     hasMore={true}
    >
       {list.map((a, i) => (
         <div key={i}>
           {a.allList}
         <div>
       ))}
   <InfiniteScroll>
```

How do I properly set the limit and make the other list appear and stop the loop?

Comment: you can refer to this case [How to paginate Cloud Firestore data with ReactJs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60381876/6322178) for more details information.

Comment: thanks, that was actually where i get the idea first but the code does the same output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got it working now, I got the idea on this [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yFlhTvxcrQ8) channel, and I also
should have defined a lastVisible in my fetchMoreData, and to stop the loop which gives an error of undefined.

```
const {list, last, setList, setLast } = ListContext(); 

const [notify, setNotify] = useState(null);

const fetchMoreData = () => {
  const field = "createdAt";

  firestoreList
    .orderBy(field, "desc")
    .startAfter(last[field]) //from Fireship channel, which loads the next data
    .limit(5)
    .get()
    .then((querySnapshot) => {
       const lastVisible = querySnapshot.docs[querySnapshot.docs.length - 1];

       const postList = []
       querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
         postList.push(doc.data());
       })

       if (lastVisible !== undefined) {
         setList([...list, ...postList]);
         setLast(lastVisible.data());

       } else {
         setNotify("nothing to load.");
         return;
       }

    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err)
    })
};
```

It also works even without using 'react-infinite-scroll-component', just by using useEffect.

Comment: Thanks for posting your solution - you've really helped me. Great code.